# centering titlebar text in a jqGrid while keeping the open/close button positioned?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, titlebar

I would like to center the titlebar text on a jqGrid without messing up the open/close image. But I've only been able to get *both* the text and open/close button-image centered. I would be grateful for some tips on how to get the text *centered* while keeping the anchor-image *positioned*.

Here's the markup that Chrome's Inspector shows:

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix">
   <a role="link" href="javascript:void(0)"
      class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton" style="right: 0px;">       
       <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span>
   </a>
   <span class="ui-jqgrid-title">Titles</span>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following

```
jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-title").replaceWith('<div style="text-align: center;"><span>' +
        jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-title").text() + '</span></div>');
```

or with

```
jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-title").replaceWith(
    '<div style="text-align: center; padding: .3em .2em .2em .3em;"><span>' +
    jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-title").text() + '</span></div>');
```

**UPDATED**: I should a little fix my solution to 1) allow `setCaption` method continue working; 2) to work correct if one have more as one jqGrid on a page:

```
var captionDiv = jQuery("#list")[0].grid.cDiv;
var titleSpan = jQuery(".ui-jqgrid-title",captionDiv);
titleSpan.css ("float", "none");
titleSpan.parent().css ("text-align", "center");
```

In the code "list" is the id of `<table>` element of the grid. DOM element of jqGrid (`jQuery("#list")[0]`) is expanded with `grid` property which has as a properties DOM elements of three important jqGrid components (`cDiv` - caption, `hDiv` - table headers and `bDiv` - table body). We use `.grid.cDiv` to get DOM element of the caption (grid header) in the most quick way. Then we give a `span` element of the caption and overwrite `"float: left"` style of the `"ui-jqgrid-title"` class which probably made you the most problem. At the end we set additional style of the parent `div` element to `"text-align: center"` to finish all work.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg, for the answer and explanation.